# Does Django Rest Framework tests use a "mock" database?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am trying to come up with the best way to test a POST only endpoint, which takes a payload and creates 6 different objects from that data.  I am trying to send the payload and then assert that all the objects that should have been created, are created.  The last block (after the new lines), is trying to repost the same load and ensure that no duplicates were created.

My question is if I run this test, is this using the existing database?  Or is it setting up a "mock" database and tearing it down after the test runs?  I don't want any of this data dirting up my db.

```
class APITests(APITestCase):
    def test_job_start(self):
        url = '/api/v1/job_start/'
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(Platform.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Platform.objects.get().name, 'andr')
        self.assertEqual(CdTool.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(CdTool.objects.get().name, 'https://jenkins-andr.test.com')
        self.assertEqual(Job.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Job.objects.get().name, 'ANDR_master_CI')
        self.assertEqual(JobExecution.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(JobExecution.objects.get().build_id, '3500')


        # Send the same payload, make sure no duplicate records are created
        response = self.client.post(url, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(Platform.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(CdTool.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Job.objects.count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(JobExecution.objects.count(), 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) From the official Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/):**

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created for the tests. Regardless of whether the tests pass or fail, the test databases are destroyed when all the tests have been executed.

**2) Your `APITestCase` extends `TestCase`, which according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#s-transactiontestcase):**

> A TestCase, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the test.Both explicit commits like transaction.commit() and implicit ones that may be caused by transaction.atomic() are replaced with a nop operation. This guarantees that the rollback at the end of the test restores the database to its initial state.